# Link to my other stack exchange sites

Tags: feature-request, area-51, stack-exchange

As a user of at least half a dozen stack exchange sites, I find myself wanting to jump quickly between sites to check on the questions I care about. It would be helpful to have an easy link to the other sites.

I'd suggest near my name at the top, a menu showing my identities on whatever other sites my OpenID is linked to. Perhaps include Area 51 in the menu too, since I'm a user on it.

Comment: Well Area51 already gives you such a link...

Answer (score 1):

In the absence of this feature request getting implemented or you picking up a third-party flair solution, you can always keep [your accounts page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1000?tab=accounts#tab-top) bookmarked.